# Can't get average grade using reduce on an object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

So, long story short, I have an object with subjects and students' grades. My job is to:
1. Calculate the average for each subject.
2. Sum up all the averages;
3. Calculate the totalAverage on all subjects.

here is my code:

```
const grades = {
    algebra: [2,3,5,2,4,3],
    geometry: [2,4,5],
    signing: [3,3,4,5],
    physics: [5,5],
    music: [2,2,5],
    english: [4,4,3],
    poetry: [5,3,4],
    chemistry: [2],
    french: [4,4]
  }

function getAverageScore(data) {

for (let subject in data) {
    let grades = data[subject];
    let average = grades.reduce((acc,curr) => {
       return acc + curr / grades.length;

    }, 0)
```

For some odd reason, this doesn't work, however, when I console.log (grades.length) it shows the length of an array with grades. What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I sum all the average grades in a resulting object? Any suggestions?

Comment: You're correctly calculating the `average` for an individual subject. Now where's the code that computes the total average?

Comment: Oh, yes, it actually works! Now I have to figure a way to add up the total average, any idea how to do that?

Comment: It works for me, after I fixed the syntax errors caused by the truncated code. What is the exact code you're running on the console, what output do you get, and what would you have expected instead?

Comment: it does work now. It didn't before. So, how do I go about getting to total average? Any idea?

Comment: Sum them up in the loop, count them in the loop, then compute the total average.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
function getAverageScore(data) {
  const listOfSubjects = Object.keys(data);
  let averagePerSubject = {};

  let sumOfAllAverages = listOfSubjects.reduce((sumOfAllAverages, subject) => {
    let grades = data[subject];
    let average = grades.reduce((acc,curr) => (acc + curr), 0) / grades.length;

    averagePerSubject[subject] = average;
    return sumOfAllAverages + average;
  }, 0);

  let averageOfAllSubjects = sumOfAllAverages / listOfSubjects.length;

  return { averagePerSubject, sumOfAllAverages, averageOfAllSubjects };
}
```

The implementation though, shows the average of all subjects, not a weighted average.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method to get the desired result:

```js
const grades = {
    algebra: [2,3,5,2,4,3],
    geometry: [2,4,5],
    signing: [3,3,4,5],
    physics: [5,5],
    music: [2,2,5],
    english: [4,4,3],
    poetry: [5,3,4],
    chemistry: [2],
    french: [4,4]
};

/*
1. Calculate the average for each subject. 
2. Sum up all the averages; 
3. Calculate the totalAverage on all subjects.
*/

const avgBySubject = Object.entries(grades).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  a[k] = a[k] || 0;
  a[k] = v.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc +=curr;
    return acc;
  } ,0) / v.length;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(`avg by subject is `, avgBySubject);

const sumAllAverages = Object.values(avgBySubject).reduce((a,c) => {
  a += c || 0;
  return a;
}, 0);

console.log(`sumAllAverages is ${sumAllAverages}`);

const theTotalAverage = sumAllAverages / Object.values(avgBySubject).length;
console.log(`theTotalAverage is: `, theTotalAverage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written solution for your problem:

```js
function getAverageScore(data) {
    let sumOfAverages = 0;
    for (let subject in data) {
        const grades = data[subject];
        const sumOfGrades = grades.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return acc + curr;
        }, 0);
        const averageOfSubject = sumOfGrades / grades.length;
        sumOfAverages += averageOfSubject;
    }
    const totalAverage = sumOfAverages / Object.keys(data).length;
    return totalAverage;
}
```

I think that above solution is so clear and obvious.

In your code you tried use `reduce()` for calculate average in wrong way.
You divided every grade by number of grades (even several times, because when you add divided grade to sum of grades, you divided it in next iterations of `reduce()` function).

Comment: sorry dude, but you're mistaken.
The sum `acc + curr / grades.length` works exactly as desired.
Though, it would be better to skip that calculation in every iteration and do it only once in the end.